# Problems with File Format UTF8

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2007

I don't know what happened.
When I try to change the encoding of a file in Delphi IDE 2007, It shows me just two options "Binary Form" and "Text Form", some one already faced this problem ? or know how to save it ?

tks for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find what I did with my IDE. 
The solution that I needed to do is remove my pc-user, to clear all the particular settings. Probably I did some mistake while working with OTA that caused this.

Tks

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're accessing the option while the Form Designer is active. That controls the format of the DFM file.

Switch to the code editor and you should have more options about the text format.

Comment: I cannot see the "file format" menu item in the context menu of the form designer, it appears only while editing the pas file.

Comment: If you right click the file's tab and choose `View as Form`, the "File Format" menu item is available

Comment: I'm even working with DFM, just with unit. 

In my Delphi options:
Together -> Default -> Source Code -> Encoding is Unicode (UTF-8) - Codepage 65001

But, even this way the code work with UTF8 characters

Comment: @jasonpenny: I didn't realize that this item is a switch. In case the form is visible it should better read "View as Text".

Comment: Saci, I don't think the word *even* means what you think it does. It is not a way of negating a statement. In fact, it intensifies a statement.

Comment: @SaCi: what has Together to do with this? I thought it is only used when modelling is enabled for a project?

Comment: @Rob: I guess SaCi was just missing a "not".

Comment: Like Rob said... Forgot a not, I'm not using any dfm file.

@Uwe Raabe, I don't know. It's the only place I found to change something related to encoding.